# Couldn't find User without an IDのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql

下記のコードで "Couldn't find User without an ID" というエラーになってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
def index
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  sort_key = (params[:column].blank? || params[:order].blank?) ? {updated_at: 'DESC'} : {params[:column] => params[:order]}

  if @user == current_user
    @origques = Origque.select('origques.*', 'count(quefavorites.id) AS favs')
    .left_joins(:quefavorites).group('origques.id').order(sort_key).where(user_id: params[:id])
    .includes(:quefavorite_users)

  else
    @origques = Origque..select('origques.*', 'count(quefavorites.id) AS favs')
    .left_joins(:quefavorites).group('origques.id').order(sort_key).where(publish_check: true)
    .where(user_id: params[:id]).includes(:quefavorite_users)
  end
end
```

viewからsortのボタンを押すとindexでエラーになります。
binding.pryをしてみたところ、`params[:id]=2` と値が取れておりました。

```
@origques = Origque.select('origques.*', 'count(quefavorites.id) AS favs')    .left_joins(:quefavorites).group('origques.id').order(sort_key).where(user_id: params[:id]) .includes(:quefavorite_users)
```

の箇所の書き方に問題があるような気もします。

原因がわかりましたら、教えてください。

**（追記）**

エラー画面でparams[:id]を検索するとnilになっているので
パラメーターが渡っていないということだと思います。

binding.pryはエラー箇所のすぐ下で実行してみました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

viewからUser.idを渡せていないとすると
下記のコードにhiddenか何かでパラメータを
渡すことができれば、解決できる気がします。

色々調べましたが、コードの書き方がわかりません。

```
<%= form_tag :user_ques, method: :get, class: "search top-margin" do %>
  <% params.slice(:column, :order).each do |key, val| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag key, val %>
  <% end %>
  <%= text_field_tag "q", params[:q], class: "search-design" %>
  <%= submit_tag "sch", class: "btn-search" %>
<% end %>
```

下記のように、<%= hidden_field_tag :id, @user.id %>を追記して
みましたが、やはり同様にcontrollerで"Couldn't find User without an ID" の
エラーになってしまいます。

```
<%= form_tag :user_ques, method: :get, class: "search top-margin" do %>
  <% params.slice(:column, :order).each do |key, val| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag key, val %>
  <% end %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :id, @user.id %>
  <%= text_field_tag "q", params[:q], class: "search-design" %>
  <%= submit_tag "sch", class: "btn-search" %>
<% end %>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
パラメータはnilとなっております。

route.rbは下記のように記載しております。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
form_tag :user_ques でviewのindexへ渡しています。

```
  resources :user_ques, only: [:index,:edit, :update, :destroy] do
    get "search", on: :collection
  end
```

button_toを使っているえerbを呼び出しており、そこにid:params[:id]を記述することで
解決できました。

```
  <li><%= button_to "⬇︎", {controller: 'user_ques', action: 'index'}, {method: :get, class: "order-button", params: {column: 'id',id:params[:id], order: 'DESC',q: params[:q]}} %>
```

Comment: １つめの画像見る限りパラメーターに id が渡ってないのに params[:id] を取り出そうとして nil になって nil で検索したから without ID エラーになってると思います。binding.pryはどこで行ったんでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。内容を本文に追記致しました。ご確認頂けると助かります。

Comment: まず例外が出ているのにその下に記述した pry に処理がいってるのはおかしいですね…　１度目にindex にきたとき正常に処理されて redirect 等で再度 index がよばれてエラーになってるのかも？　エラーの直前にpryを入れてみたらどうなりますか？　もう１点最初のSSとパラメータの中身が違っていてid:2のハッシュを文字列にしたようなおかしな値が入ってます。これでもやはりparams[:id]で値がとれてるとは思えないです

Comment: 質問の投稿時、外部サービスを使わずに画像を直接貼り付けることができますので次回からお試しください。

Comment: hidden_field_tag :id, <値> とかけば渡すことはできますが値に何を渡したいのかはロジックを考えてる質問者さん自身じゃないとわからないと思います

Comment: <%= hidden_field_tag :id, @user.id %>を追記してみましたが同様のエラーになってしまいます。

Comment: それで params[:id] に値が入らないのはなぞですね。パラメータにはなにがわたっていますか？　あと route.rb もはってほしいです。普通 index はコレクションだと思うんですが、パスに :id がはいってたりするとGETパラメータと被った場合に変な挙動するかもです。あと form_tag は index で view でいいんですよね？　あとコードが断片的なので if params = ... とか if @user = ... みたいなミスで途中で代入しちゃってたりしないですか？

Comment: パラメータはnilになっております。route.rb を貼り付けしました。

Comment: @user = User.find(params[:id])でエラーが出るなら pry までいかないはずなので、どこで nil になってるか正確に記述してほしいです。できれば pry じゃなくエラー画面にでてる request parameter をはってください。画像の2枚でも request parameter に違いがありますし、form をかえたならまた変わってるはずです

Comment: 呼び出している部分テンプレートにid:params[:id]の記載が漏れておりました。これで解決いたしました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 解決した場合には、質問文への追記やコメントではなく、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 2):

各erbファイルに
 <%= hidden_field_tag :id, @user.id %>
と
id:params[:id]
を追記することで解決できました。